# Parse Cloud Code Deploy Error

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to deploy my parse cloud code, but for some reason I am getting the error `Error talking to the Parse servers; please try again.` I have never had this problem before deploying parse cloud code, and I don't know where it would be coming from. I only have one cloud code file, main.js in the cloud directory.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error?

**Edit**

This actually happens any time I try to run a parse command... still no idea why.

**EDIT 2**

Running parse update i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 708, in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 511, in handle_update
  File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 20, in download_and_save
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 427, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1247, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by (on Mac OSX) running

```
brew reinstall python
brew install openssl
```

as per suggestion here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/CuhagsCapOw